# import existing files from Perforce version control

Tags: qt-creator

In Qt creator, I can start a new project with Perforce version control. But how can I open a existing source repo like "File->open file/project-> my.pro" AND use the existing Perforce client?
Git, CVS and svn have their checkout commands(File->New->Version Control) in qt creator, Perforce not.
I can add the current client to preferences, but only for *one* client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried more recent versions of Qt Creator?  This was asked a while ago.  I am currently using Qt Creator and am able to check out files from my Perforce client with now issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I'm tumbleweed now.

Sorry I have to use Perforce. I hate it, I will never bother you again with it. It's broken in so many levels. I will manually edit the file myprojects.files untill someone comes up with a creator plugin for that.
As alternative, I like to use git with my perforce projects, so this enables creator projects as well.